# Vue does not compile .scss files with comment "//"

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass

I'm quite new to vue.js and little bit stack.

In my `.scss` file I have commented line like:

```
//   overflow: hidden;
```

But when I keep this line, I'm getting error:

> Unknown word

and compiler highlighting this comment. I saw that it is related to webpack config, but I don't have `webpack.config.js` file, I have only `vue.config.js` file and not sure how to config it to work properly. This is my config file, which is including variables file to all styles.

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: `@import "@/styles/_variables.scss";`
      }
    }
  }
};
```

I have sass-loader package installed and it is working fine - issue only with comments in `.scss` file.
I also found https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/171 but they are talking about `webpack.config.js` which I don't have.

Comment: This might help you with editing the webpage.config.js from vue.config.js: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#replacing-loaders-of-a-rule

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Changing the vue.config.js file is bit complex.
But this problem was resolved when I used **lang="scss"** in app.js where all my css imports were present.

```
<style lang="scss">
...
@import './stylesheets/custom.scss';
...
</stlye>
```